# Windows SBS2011 Remote Web Access, access denied

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-sbs-2011

An internal network of a workplace that I manage is changing its servers from SBS 2011 up to Full Server 2012 R2, so I am decommissioning the SBS 2011 slowly (can´t remove it completely, some legacy things on it that we still need).

The SBS 2011 has been the Remote Web Access server for a long time and has worked I think up until now (I am inheriting this setup, the former admin has quit). But now when I try to log in a normal user then I can´t, just get a `The user name or password is incorrect` message as if it is not getting the right credentials. If I log in with administrator rights then that works, since I think that is a local user on the SBS.

Now here is the thing, I have removed the Active Directory from the SBS (which does break the SBS license I think, but lets let that slide for the moment please, this is an ongoing transition), the full server is now the domain controller and is basically the heart of the domain. But I need to have the RWA and Remote Desktop Gateway work correctly on the SBS (don´t have access to the router to forward anything to another server, that is handled by the ISP).

So my question is, is there any way for the RWA and RDG to get credentials from the Active Directory without any AD services up and running on the SBS? Or is there something else going on that I am not aware of?

EDIT: Just tried to create a new user on the new full server 2012 and that user can log on fine to the RWA so it seems the authentication works, then it is a question of why users that were created x many years ago do not get access (have only tried one user so far, don´t have the passwords for any other).

Comment: How did you remove AD from the SBS server?

Comment: From Server Manager (not the SBS console), right clicked the roles concerned with AD and removed them.

Comment: Doing that you should have been prompted that the server is a Domain Controller and that you need to demote it before removing the Roles. So did you demote it first then?

Comment: @joeqwerty I seem to recall demoting it before trying to remove the roles (its been a while since I did this, don´t recall exactly the order of events). But the SBS is no longer listed as a domain controller in the domain. It is a part of the domain though, but just as a normal client I think.